# ng-repeat not working when given a dynamic index in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this array in `$scope.types` (example data) :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "description": "Cat",
    "property_type": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "Nickname",
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "description": "Age",
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "description": "Color",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to populate a `ng-repeat` with the properties of the type. Here's what I did :

```
<div ng-repeat="property in types[parseInt($('#select_type').val())].property_type">
  {{property.description}}
</div>
```

This code doesn't show anything. However, if I replace `$('#select_type').val()` with `0`, which is the offset of the object in the array, it works. What I don't understand is that if I look in the console what's the value of `$('#select_type').val()`, I get `"0"`... so it should work, unless there's something I don't get right with Angular (which is probably the case here).

If it can help, here's my select :

```
<select ng-options="type.id as type.description for type in types" ng-model="current_data.object_type_id" id="select_type">
  <!-- Generated by ng-options, not hardcoded -->
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Cat</option>
  <option value="1">Dog</option>
</select>
```

Have any idea?

Comment: Never use JQuery with Angularjs in this way...

Comment: I know it's bad practice, but I have a strong jQuery background and close to no Angular background ... it's a little hard to make the complete jump

Comment: @SamuelBolduc -- I'm in the same boat as you, strong jQuery with little Angular background. Don't mix the two like this, if you're going to make the jump and use Angular, it's best to learn it the right way, even if it is more difficult in the beginning.

Comment: I would recommend throwing away JQuery entirely until you get used to Angular. You don't need it.

Comment: Yes I'll try to separate both as much as possible. But for UI manipulations (animations mostly) I still need jQuery... Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the following code:

---

```
<div ng-repeat="property in current_data.property_type">
   {{property.description}}
</div>
<select ng-options="type.description for type in types" ng-model="current_data" id="select_type">
<option value="">select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer. I also ended up with the same solution. http://jsfiddle.net/dgN3Q/

Comment: Yes, this is the right solution I was looking for! I was trying to find a way to do it with only Angular. Tnanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="property in types[current_data.object_type_id].property_type">
  {{property_type.description}}
</div>
```

Comment: It was a mistake, I corrected it, sorry! I did not have this mistake in my application

Comment: Yes it's done, I just changed this little mistake, the question is still the same

Comment: The value `current_data.object_type_id`, when you select in dropdown is `1`. You object `types` only has 1 item (at index 0), so it may not be binding correctly.